# Oauth2 Spring Security Resource Server and Independent Auth Server

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, amazon-cognito

everyone!
I'm new to Oauth2 and I've had different approaches with it.

I have a doubt. I'm actually building a Provider Server with Spring Security and I have an external access token provider (Google and AWS Cognito).

I know the process to get the access token following the code grant flow (Which is the one I want to implement). I built an Android app that gets the code and changes it for the access token.

My question is:
How do I validate that the token I'm sending to the Provider Server is a valid one using Spring Security to also access the protected resources that the server has?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two alternatives either u get the public key and verify the token urself or maybe they have an endpoint where you can send the token and know if its a valid one or not.

Something like this

```
GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
    // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
    .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID))
    // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
    //.setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3))
    .build();

// (Receive idTokenString by HTTPS POST)

GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
if (idToken != null) {
  Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

  // Print user identifier
  String userId = payload.getSubject();
  System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);

  // Get profile information from payload
  String email = payload.getEmail();
  boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
  String name = (String) payload.get("name");
  String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
  String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
  String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
  String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");

  // Use or store profile information
  // ...

} else {
  System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
}
```

Link: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth